# Model Field with only year or full date using Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

How can I get a model field in which I would once add full date in format like `2016-07-04` and once only a year like `1997`, so that I would have two items: one with only a year and one with full date.

And then I could sort them by year.

Answer (score 1):

For sorting and filtering by year you can also use the `date` field directly; to filter you use [`__year`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#year) like `.filter(date__year=1234)` and when sorting by date then the instances are sorted (obviously) by year.

But if that doesn't solve your situation, you could also add an `IntegerField` (or `PositiveIntegerField`) to your model where you enter only the year. For example:

```
class Document(models.Model):
    ...
    year = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    date = models.DateField()
    ...
```